# How to create Multi-metric Alarm?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, cloudwatch-alarms

There are multiple instances with servicename-N running & i am able to push custom metric using python sdk to Namespace-X. However when i create alarm it only let me select One metric from one of the instances. i have tried Metric Math based alarm but the email notification doesnt include detail information(serviceName, instanceID).
Any pointers to achieve this(eg. have meta data like serviceName in notification email) ?
[scenario image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWoBv.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating a Metric Insights alarm (https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/12/amazon-cloudwatch-metrics-insights-alarms/).

> Amazon CloudWatch Metrics Insights alarms enables customers to alarm on entire fleets of dynamically changing resources with a single alarm using standard SQL queries...With Metric Insights alarms you can set alarms using Metric Insight queries that monitor multiple resources without having to worry if the resources are short lived or not. For example, you can set a single alarm that alerts when any of your EC2 instances reaches a high threshold for CPU utilization and the alarm will evaluate new instances that are launched afterwards.

Alternatively, you can create an alarm for each individual time series and then create a composite alarm that groups the individual alarms. You can then put your action on the composite alarm. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Create_Composite_Alarm.html